# Filling a dictionary with multiple user input

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary that stores user data to create a profile for that user. But anytime I run my program and enter the escape word to quit running the program the program only print the last few pieces of information entered by the user (the last profile to say). But I want to be able to save and print each profile like it's its dictionary, so it should be list a nested dictionary and save in a json file but I'm stuck.

Here is my code:

```
def collect_data():
    """Collect user input to build a dating profile and store it in a
    dictionary """
    date_profile = {}
    dating_file = "dating_profile.json"

    while True:
        # Prompt the user for his/her name, age, gender, date of birth and
        # location
        name = "name"
        first_name = input("Enter your first name: ")
        if first_name == 'quit':
            break
        surname = "surname"
        last_name = input("Enter your last name: ")
        if last_name == 'quit':
            break
        sex = "sex"
        gender = input("What is your gender? Male or Female: ")
        if gender == 'quit':
            break
        lifespan = "age"
        age = input("Enter your age: ")
        try:
            age = int(age)
        except ValueError:
            print(input("Invalid value! Please enter your age"))
        locality = "location"
        location = input("Please enter your location: ")
        if location == 'pass':
            pass
        elif location == 'quit':
            break
        # Store the user's data in a dictionary
        date_profile[name] = first_name
        date_profile[surname] = last_name
        date_profile[sex] = gender
        date_profile[lifespan] = age
        date_profile[locality] = location
        with open(dating_file, 'a') as f:
            json.dump(str([date_profile]), f)


def retrieve_data():
    """Re-downloads the data stored in dating_file.json"""
    with open("dating_profile.json") as f_object:
        download_profile = json.load(f_object)
        print(download_profile)


collect_data()
retrieve_data()
```

And here is the error message I got in the terminal: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pixgi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of items:

You can save some code by creating a dictionary with the keys already populated and then just iterating over the keys to prompt the user.

The way you are dumping your json is not correct.  I am surprised it is reading it back in.  The top level json structure for you file should be a list.  Inside of the list is a collection of the user profile dictionaries.  When adding a new dictionary, you will need to read in the file contents, append the new dict, then write out the entire file again.

It helps in the long run to break out separate tasks into individual functions.  It makes the code easier to manage.

```py
import os
import json

def collect_data():
    """Collect user input to build a dating profile and store it in a
    dictionary """
    date_profile = {
        'first_name' : '',
        'surname': '',
        'gender': '',
        'age': '',
        'location': ''
    }

    validations = {
        'first_name' : (None, None),
        'surname': (None, None),
        'gender': (validate_gender, 'Please select either "male" or "female".'),
        'age': (int, 'Age must be an integer.'),
        'location': (None, None)
    }

    for key in date_profile:
        value = query_user(key)
        if value is None:
            return
        validate, msg = validations.get(key)
        if validate:
            retry = True
            while retry: 
                try:
                    validate(value)
                    retry = False
                except:
                    print(msg)
                    value = query_user(key)
                    if value is None:
                        return
        date_profile[key] = value
    return date_profile

def export_profile(file_path, date_profile):
    # read in json, or create new list
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path) as fp:
            j_data = json.load(fp)
    else:
        j_data = []
    j_data.append(data_profile)
    # write out
    with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(j_data, fp)

def query_user(key):
    query = "Enter your {} (type 'quit' to exit): ".format(key.replace('_', ' '))
    value = input(query)
    if value.lower() == 'quit':
        print('Exiting.')
        return None
    return value

def validate_gender(g):
    assert g.lower() in ('male', 'female')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp = collect_data()
    export_profile("dating_profile.json", dp)
```

To run this, save it to a python file, such as `collect.py` and run:

```
python collect.py
```

Comment: Also I wanted to ask. In the first except statement you wrote what is the exception for?

Comment: No problem.  If it answers your question, please click the check mark next to the answer.  The except block will catch any exception arsing from trying to validate the data entry.  You could write it as two except block, one for `ValueError` and another for `AssertionError`, but the code in the blocks would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 json object in your file, it's not valid anymore, that's why you get the error. You should append your `date_profile` to a list and rewrite the whole file every time, or have one file per profile.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is not valid. You can use a [validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to validate it.
A quick fix would be to store it in an array and dump once.

```
[
{profile_1},
{profile_2},
{profile_3}
]
```

An alternate to persisting data would be [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). 
Although I recommend you use a database to store your data.